# Firebase hosting with url dynamic paramaters?

Tags: javascript, firebase, url-routing, url-parameters, firebase-hosting

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to understand the limits of Firebase hosting.
I've created a static webpage that adjusts the content via the url paramaters. 
For example the following url will provide me with the data I need to populate my webpage. http://example.com/recipe?name=pizza&time=30&lang=en
The url itself it obviously dynamic (values may change)

My question is can I do that with firebase hosting?
It seems you can redirect urls, but not to set a route.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase definitely provides the domain. I don't think it will automagically handle the query parameters for you. For that you will need some sort of front-end routing mechanism. Check out this article on building a [VanillaJS router](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/A-modern-JavaScript-router-in-100-lines-history-api-pushState-hash-url) and how to take advantage of the [HTML5 History API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

For instance, I write VueJS apps and I use their vue-router package to handle app routing. It works flawlessly on Firebase apps.

That said, Firebase now has **[Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)** which, I heard, allow you to run server-side code, like a NodeJS. So maybe you can use that feature to handle your params and build your static page accordingly before serving it to your visitor.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using vue-router it it works perfectly on Firebase but if I send a user a link like: myapp.com/your-account I get a 404 page. They have to enter through the root and work their way through the app.

Comment: @Rory I know its been a while since you posted this but any update / advice on this? Having the same issue, just getting a blank page instead of a 404